# ajax widgets in pyramid and chameleon

Tags: python, ajax, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

I would like to be able to easily create ajax 'widgets' backed by chameleon and pyramid on the server side.

Does Pyramid provide any plumbing code that would make writing widgets easy?

My current approach is I have a home view which uses home.pt as the renderer.  home.pt uses a macro base.pt which defines the page structure and provides a slot for home.pt to fill.  base.pt also uses a login 'widget' macro that I have written (see: account_login_widget.pt below).

In theory, this all sounds great...I have a reusable login widget that I can use in many pages, but my current approach doesn't work very well.  My login widget uses variables like ${username} in its renderer (which the server needs to define).  I want the login widget and its rendering to be as independent as possible.  But with my current way of doing things, the home view code needs to be aware of the login widget's needs and provide username, formrender and other variables in the dictionary.  Definitely not good...

I feel like I'm close to the right idea, but missing some things...

Any thoughts?

base.pt:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <span metal:use-macro="load: account_login_widget.pt"></span>     
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        <span metal:define-slot="content"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.pt:

```
<div metal:use-macro="load: base.pt">
<span metal:fill-slot="content">
    <div>my stuff</div>
</span>
</div>
```

account_login_widget.pt:

```
<span metal:define-macro="account_login_widget">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $.fn.my_function = function() {
        $('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // ajax call
            $.post(some_url, some_data, function(response) {
                $('#account_login_widget').html(response);
            });
        };
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

// Define the entry point    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).my_function();
});
</script>

<div id="account_login_widget">
<div id="login_bar" tal:condition="not username">
    ${form_renderer.begin(...)}
        ... my form ...
    ${form_renderer.end()}
    <span tal:condition="login_failed">Login failed</span>
    <div id="forgot_password_link"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></div>
    <div id="create_account_link"><a href="${signup_url}">Create Account</a></div>
</div>
<div tal:condition="username">
    Welcome <strong>${username}</strong>! <a href="${logout_url}">Logout</a>
</div>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: I should mention my current thinking is to have a BaseView class that all my views will extend.  In this BaseView class I could have an add Widget method that will take my widget view object and add all its variable dependencies to the dict that my view will eventually return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good way of dealing with this is to associate your account_login_widget with its own view, like:

```
@view_config(name='login_widget',
             renderer='templates/account_login_widget.pt')
def login_widget(request):
    return {'username': ...}
```

You should then be able to visit http://yourapp/login_widget and get back only the widget's HTML.

What's left to do is to call the view and include the resulting HTML in your template.  That is, instead of:

```
<span metal:use-macro="load: account_login_widget.pt"></span>
```

you'll want something like:

```
<span tal:replace="structure render_view('login_widget')"></span>
```

`render_view` however doesn't exist in templates; you'll have to provide it yourself.  It's best to use the Before Render Event for this: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/narr/hooks.html#beforerender-event

```
from pyramid.events import subscriber
from pyramid.events import BeforeRender
from pyramid.view import render_view_to_response

@subscriber(BeforeRender)
def add_render_view_global(event):
    event['render_view'] = lambda name: render_view_to_response(context, request, name, secure).ubody
```

Done. This approach will also help should you ever need to (re)load widgets dynamically through AJAX.

Comment: Thanks!  This strategy sounds pretty good and gets me far.  There is still a kink or two though.  Does your suggestion assume use of traversal?  I'm using url dispatch.  The problem I have is the '@view_config' doesn't specify a route_name so the url: http://yourapp/login_widget isn't found (this also means my ajax post doesn't work).  But when I specify the route_name in addition to name, then the call to render_view_to_response() doesn't resolve to a view.  It seems I can only specify 'name' or 'route_name' in the '@view_config', but not both.  What's going wrong here?

Comment: Adding two view_configs seems to do the trick.  The combined predicates were overly specific.  But adding 2 view_configs seems awkward too.   @view_config(name='account_login_widget', renderer='template/account_login_widget.pt')
@view_config(route_name='account_login_widget', renderer='template/account_login_widget.pt')

Comment: You're right. The view configuration bit of my answer (`@view_config`) assumes traversal. The view configuration will differ if you're using url dispatch.  http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/narr/urldispatch.html#route-configuration